# 'Please check the number' exception in vb.net ms access project

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

I am building vb.net-ms access database project.
In one of the `Insert` command, I am getting `"Please check the number"` exception pointing at `ExecuteNonQuery` code line.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

    If cbMachine.SelectedIndex <> -1 And _
       cbShift.SelectedIndex <> -1 And _
       cbWdiv.SelectedIndex <> -1 And _
       cbChky.SelectedIndex <> -1 And _
       cbBukby.SelectedIndex <> -1 And _
       cbRemarks.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO buktab ([Booking Date],[Machine Type],[Shift],[MS Division / Ward], Chowky, [Booked By], [Site Address], [Remarks]) VALUES(" &
            DateTimePicker1.Value.Date & ", '" & cbMachine.Text & "', '" & cbShift.Text & "', '" & cbWdiv.Text & "', '" & cbChky.Text & "', '" & cbBukby.Text & "', '" & cbSite.Text & "', '" & cbRemarks.Text & "');"

        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MsgBox("Machine Booked Successfully!")
        'Resetting all comboboxes
        DateTimePicker1.Text = Today()
        cbMachine.SelectedIndex = -1
        cbShift.SelectedIndex = -1
        cbWdiv.SelectedIndex = -1
        cbChky.SelectedIndex = -1
        cbBukby.SelectedIndex = -1
        cbSite.Text = "Please Type Manually"
        cbRemarks.SelectedIndex = -1
    Else
        MsgBox(" Please Enter the Missing Values")
    End If
    cmdInsert.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Always use parameters.  The DateTimePicker1.Value looks like the culprit since it isn't properly encased.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, do yourself a favour and use a parameterized query, like this

```vb
cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
cmdInsert.CommandText = _
        "INSERT INTO buktab ([Booking Date],[Machine Type],[Shift],[MS Division / Ward], Chowky, [Booked By], [Site Address], [Remarks]) " & _
        "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbMachine.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbShift.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbWdiv.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbChky.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbBukby.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbSite.Text)
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cbRemarks.Text)
cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

**Edit re: "Please check the number" exception**

Launch Access and open the table in Design View. Check the `Validation Rule` and `Validation Text` properties for each of the fields you are trying to insert. I suspect that one of those fields has a (fairly useless) `Validation Text` message set to "Please check the number".

Comment: still getting same exception "Please check the number"

Comment: @user2988513 Try doing the INSERT without [Booking Date]. (Remove it from the field list, remove one of the `?, ` parameters in the `VALUES` clause, and comment out the corresponding `.AddWithValue` line.) Does that work?

Comment: @user2988513 I have updated my answer. That exception message may be a `Validation Text` setting on one of the fields in the Access database.